# How to pass an abstract argument in fortran 2003/08

Tags: fortran, abstract, virtual-functions

I am working on a module that should treat different geometry entity in 2D and 3D. 
I wrote a set of abstract type that then I specialized. The basic type look like

```
type, abstract :: Emplo
    contains
    procedure (Compute_EmploSeniority), deferred :: EmploAge
    generic :: Compute_Salary => Comp_Sal_Director, Comp_Sal_SaleManager 
end type Emplo

type, abstract, extends(Emplo) :: SalesManager
  ...
  contains
  ...
end type SalesManager
```

It gets specialized in

```
type, extends(SalesManager) :: SalesManager_IT
  contains
    ...
end type SalesManager_IT

type, extends(SalesManager) :: SalesManager_HW
  contains
    ...
end type SalesManager_HW
```

Anyway I would like to have only one function Comp_Sal_SaleManager because the salary is computed in the very same way and just the data on  which it is computed slightly differs.
For this reason I would like to have something like

```
function Comp_Sal_SaleManager(SalesManager)
    type(SalesManager) :: SM_ID
end function
```

The error I get (gfortran) is exactly that SM_ID is an abstract type. My goal indeed is to use the parent and then get the data of the specific type, iterate on that and return the result of Comp_Sal_SaleManager.
Even if I know what I'd like to do I could not find on the internet any help. Am I doing something totally weird in Fortran or in general? How could I solve this?

The only solution I thought is to carry on the virtual function and specialize it in every non-abstract type. On the other hand this carry a lot of code duplicaiton and it kind of defeats the purpouse of OOP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, use `type(atype)` to declare a non-polymorphic object and `class(atype)` a polymorphic object.

As an abstract type, you cannot have any non-polymorphic objected defined as that type.  That is, you cannot have an actual `type(SalesManager)` object anywhere, whether it is an argument or not.

In your virtual function, the argument will always be a derived type of `SalesManager` therefore you should define the argument as `class(SalesManager)`, creating a polymorphic object that can be of any derived type that ultimately extends `SalesManager`.

Even if `SalesManager` is not abstract and the function is not a virtual function, you still have to declare the argument using `class()` to be able to accept an object that is derived from `SalesManager`.  Using `type()` will only allow object of exactly that type.